# Responsive navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my navigation responsive, I have no idea how, it want it so it doesn't jump of to the next line, I know that the padding is causing this and I could help this by using percentages as width but that looks hella ugly.

This is how the page looks on normal resolution:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5ZXB.jpg

This is how it looks when I zoom in.. (this is what I don't want to happen):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gDMd.jpg

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Code for navigation:

```css
.header-side .game {
  float: right;
}

.header-side .selected {
  color: #f7c22c;
}

.header-side .other {
  float: left;
}

.bottom-header {
  height: 115px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #343538;
  display: flex;
  color: #787878;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

.top-header {
  height: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #343538;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-side {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header-middle {
  width: 10%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-divider {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #f7c22c;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top-header">
    This is the top header!
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-header">
    <div class="header-side">
      <div class="nav-item game">skin upgrade</div>
      <div class="nav-item game">skin royale</div>
      <div class="nav-item game selected">skin crash</div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-middle">
      <div class="header-divider">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-side">
      <div class="nav-item other">deposit</div>
      <div class="nav-item other">withdraw</div>
      <div class="nav-item other">provably fair</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use media query in css like that:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  element {padding: 0;}
}
```

So, when the the resolution get into 768px, it will remove the padding of the element.

Comment: Okay, so I tried doing this now but the padding doesn't seem to go away?

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-item {
   padding: 0;
  }
 }

Comment: Remember to use media query in the end of css, and try use !important to force the css attribute

Comment: isn't !important a bad thing? :>

EDIT: I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: If you cant avoid `!important` it's better.. Don't you have the full code on codepen or something like that? So, I can help you more effectively

Comment: I will make a pen tommorow, I'm just to tired now at 3AM and I'm gonna go to sleep. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
Or you could go with percentage. After all a desktop webpage wouldnt look any better in a 420p screen.
I would suggest to go with something more "low resolution", such as a mobile design, so using media queries is probably the best you can do.

EDIT: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
This is what you want.

Comment: Well, the easiest way to test for me if something is responsive is just to zoom in and out, that's how I usually do it.

Comment: Well, if you are using chrome, you could enable dev tools (F12) and on the top right corner you have some mobile emulators.

Comment: ah, that helps for responsive checking. Thanks, but still does media works on chrome?

Comment: Yes, I mean, it is used almost in every single webpage. Make sure to set your viewport tag and you are good. At a later time you might want to add a mobile to desktop switcher (basically switching from mobile view in desktop view) and viewport is what is most commonly used (as far as i have seen).